# Error while installing app with flavored package

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-build-flavors

I'm trying to have flavored package names in my app. I've applied following changes:

```
productFlavors {
    production {
        applicationId "com.xxx"
    }
    staging {
        applicationId "com.xxx.staging"
    }
}
```

And when trying to install the app I get:

```
Installation failed with message INSTALL_FAILED_CONFLICTING_PROVIDER.
It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing
version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.

WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!

Do you want to uninstall the existing application?
```

After accepting an error occurs:

```
$ adb shell pm uninstall com.xxx.staging
DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR
Error while Installing APK
```

Seems like it's trying to delete something that doesn't exist... Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like it's something to do with `android:authorities` in the manifest.  Did you search for the error message?

Answer (score 0):

do you have an apk already installed on device? if so it might a your using diff keystores to sign your apk (i.e. 1 file for signing prod & staging apk and a diff file for debug - usually contained somewhere in your 'android-sdk' / .android dir... you can try adding the '-r' flag to your adb install cmd in order to replace an already installed apk on your device (if exists)